# Creating new Field in all Documents from two existing Field in that index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Firstly, totally new to the ELK stack so still struggling with the terminology.

I have been trying to create some visualizations and discovered that merging fields via a JSON scipt is kind of finicky, and apparently not recommended.

eg, I want to visualize the number of unique sessions but the sessions are only unique to a given hostname, therefore this script in the aggregation achieves that.

```
{
  "script": {
  "source": "doc['hostname.keyword'].value + doc['session_id.keyword'].value",
  "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

So it turns out from my research that what I should do is add another Field during my GROK parsing so that this field exists in each document, making the search faster.

So, the Grok part can be done with the following:

```
add_field => { "hostname_session_id" => "%{hostname}:%{session_id}" }
```

So what's missing for me, is how I go about updating all the entries already in the index so they have this field added historically and what's the best way to do this on a live system where the index is getting appended too?

My Grok currently creates a new index each day, and I am up too day two, so one static Index and another one that's still being appended too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) API to update existing documents, with a script that specifies how to generate the new field.